# T function in OTG oven

Tags: oven, toasting

What does T stand for in OTG oven? If it is for Toasting then can an OTG oven be used in place of a toaster to toast a bread or it serves some different functionality in OTG oven?

Answer (score 2):

OTG means **O**ven **T**oaster **G**rill

Such ovens have a top and bottom electric heating element. The top element serves broil and to toast. Depending on size you might be able to toast on both sides at once with only the wire grate.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. And if your toaster is broken can an OTG be fully used in place of it?